# EF record update creates new record for related object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an EntityFramework code first project with two objects width a relationship.

Code example:

```
public class A{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public B b{get;set;}
}
```

when i call:

```
_context.A.Attach(a);
_context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I successfully update A but i get a new record in table B.

How can i avoid this so that when i update A i also update B not createing av new one?

Comment: have you tried `context.A.AddOrUpdate(a);`

Comment: `IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate` ... just no (and that's from [Julie Lerman](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't do things in a detached context this way — it's error prone — but the solution for similar things in an attached context is an `Include`:

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    context.A.Include(a => a.B).Attach(a);
    context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```